# Can't present items from Firebase Database in TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't present my objects obtained from Database.
I declared array for containing my items to present:

```
var tournaments = [TournamentItem]()
```

My structure's TournamentItem init function:

```
init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) {

    key = snapshot.key
    ref = snapshot.ref
    type = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("type").value as! String
    name = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("name").value as! String
    numberOfParticipants = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("numberOfParticipants").value as! Int
    tournamentMode = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("mode").value as! Bool
    completed = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("completed").value as! Bool
}
```

Function to obtaining data looks like:

```
func getTournamentListSnapshot() {

    ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        //print("\(snapshot.key) -> \(snapshot.value)")


        for item in snapshot.children {

            let tournamentItem = TournamentItem(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            self.tournaments.append(tournamentItem)

        }
        if self.tournaments.isEmpty { //not a subject of discussion
            self.showAlertOfEmptyTournamentsArray()
        }

    })
}
```

And i call this inside my ViewDidLoad method.
The problem is that after calling this methods my array is empty but Firebase Database is not.
I have tried to debug this whole thing but i can't find any solution to this problem.

My TableViewController delegate methods looks like this:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.tournaments.count
}
```

Comment: Did you forgot to call `tableView.reloadData()` after `if self.tournaments.isEmpty { //not a subject of discussion
            self.showAlertOfEmptyTournamentsArray()
        }` ?

Comment: Are you checking the array before after the asynchronous callback from observeEventType?

Comment: @Santosh that was the case here. Now it's working properly, thanks!

Comment: Great! I have added it in answer, accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `tableView.reloadData()` after or may be in `else`:

```
if self.tournaments.isEmpty { 
  self.showAlertOfEmptyTournamentsArray() 
} 
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: You need to click on the green Right Mark to accept it as answer not just upvoting.